# Button Not Functioning When Clicked

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, forms

When I click the button on my form nothing happens completely nothing. I tried almost every troubleshooting that I can, but nothing happened. I am a newbie please help guys. Thanks in advance experts.

```
Imports System.Convert
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form3
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Public frm1 As Form1
Private frm4 As Form4


Public Sub New1(ByVal callerInstance As Form1)

    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm1 = callerInstance
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim frm1 As Form1 = Form1
    Dim frm4 As Form4 = Form4



    'program execution proper

    Dim lbl3 As Integer = CInt(frm4.Label3.Text)

    If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox2.Text.Trim(), TextBox1.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        lbl3 = (lbl3) + 1
        frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)
        If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox4.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            lbl3 = (lbl3) + 1
            frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)
            If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox6.Text.Trim(), TextBox3.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                lbl3 = (lbl3) + 1
                frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)


                If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox8.Text.Trim(), TextBox4.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                    lbl3 = (lbl3) + 1
                    frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)

                    If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox10.Text.Trim(), TextBox5.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                        'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1 
                        frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)

                        If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox12.Text.Trim(), TextBox6.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                            lbl3 = (lbl3) + 1
                            frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)

                            If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox14.Text.Trim(), TextBox7.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                                lbl3 = (lbl3) + 1
                                frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)

                                If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox16.Text.Trim(), TextBox8.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                                    lbl3 = (lbl3) + 1
                                    frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)

                                    If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox18.Text.Trim(), TextBox9.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                                        lbl3 = (lbl3) + 1
                                        frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)

                                        If Not String.Equals(frm1.TextBox20.Text.Trim(), TextBox10.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then lbl3 += 1
                                        lbl3 = (lbl3) + 1

                                        frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)

                                        If frm1.Label1.Text = TextBox9.Text Then
                                            lbl3 += 0
                                            frm4.Show(Me)
                                            Me.Hide()


                                        Else

                                            lbl3 = (lbl3) + 0
                                            frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)
                                            frm4.Show(Me)
                                            Me.Hide()

                                        End If
                                        If frm4 IsNot Nothing Then
                                            frm4.Visible = False

                                            frm4.Show(Me) 'Show Second Form  

                                            Me.Hide()
                                        End If

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If


End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point in the Click event and following it with the debugger?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman hi sir thanks for your input. Yes I tried but I did not see anything suspicious :(

Comment: So when you step through the code, are you checking the values of each of the textboxes to see if your conditionals are working correctly?

Comment: First check if its happening on another event. Drop a new button on your form, double click it to create the handle. Then inside put a messagebox and see if it gets hit. Set a breakpoint on the sub.

Comment: You are not initializing the frm variables, missing `New` keyword.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Hi sir thanks for your input. I tried putting another button and it functioned and nothing suspicious on the breakpoint

Comment: @OneFineDay Its okay to put a New keyword even if the form has values and is existing? Thanks

Comment: Thats funny you said the button isnt functioning, therefore its your logic in the button.

Comment: Well your using a variable so you must initialize that object otherwise it will be null. What do you mean by existing? All classes exist, but must be initialized to run properly.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR I mean it worked haha

Comment: @OneFineDay I am afraid that if i put a New it will call a new instance that can affect on the logic of the program and the values that exists on the form and call it otherwise or nulled. Thanks

Comment: All classes that are being USED as an object must be instantiated.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Hi sir what do you mean by "instantiated"? Please can you give an example or elaborate it more? Thanks in advance

Comment: What @onefineday said. But he said all classes must be initialized, thats a vague statement becuase they dont have to be unless you have it as an object that your going to use.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR because if i will put New to it then it will not read the values that is existing on the previous form? correct me if im wrong thanks.

Comment: For example: i have a class that has a function i need to use, i dont have to instantiate it for it to work because i may not be using any properties and such from that class. But if i was in another class i would need to instantiate it to use that class properties and such in another class.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Now I got the point I need to instantiate it because its in another class. But the question is how? I searched google and I did not find any.. Can you give me an example please? Thanks a lot sir

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Vb.net like VB6 as a provides a [default instance](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html) that can be accessed by directly addressing the Form's Class, it does not have to have New called on it since it is provided by VB. This "feature" was put in for backwards compatibility with older versions of VB, but it is the source of problems and a source of a lot of questions on this site.

Comment: Correct @MarkHall, never said "New" had to be used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by removing the "Me" on `frm4.show(Me)` and changed it to `frm4.show()` Because I have two forms declared on the handle of button click event.

Comment: Good... you caught it then :)